# Is there an efficient algorithm for calculating shortest path for multiple (source,target) pairs in a graph?

Tags: graphs, shortest-path, dijkstras-algorithm

I wonder if there is an algorithm which takes multiple (source,target) pairs and a max_depth parameter and returns all or some of the paths found with those pairs?

Thinking of Dijkstra's algorithm, it would start from each start node and then in each iteration it would also check other pairs' tables to see if there is a path found from it's current node to it's end node. By this way, the algorithm can take advantage of the all computations made for each pairs.

My dataset is dbpedia and wikidata entities and properties (unweighted) and I want to find all/some shortest paths from given nodes from and to each other. Say you have entities A,B,C,D,E. I want to find relations between A and B, A and C, A and D, A and E, B and C, B and D and so on... I mentioned max depth because the graph is big and there are too many operations so if a path cannot be found within the given max depth, the algorithm halts the execution for that pair.

Comment: What is the desired output from the algorithm?  What is meant by "max_depth" and how is it supposed to affect the output?   What do you mean by "all of those paths"?  Are you looking for shortest paths?  What kind of graph is this?  Is it a weighted graph or unweighted graph? What's the context where you encountered this task or the motivation?  Can you credit the book or source where you saw it?  I encourage you to [edit] the question to define the question more precisely.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#All-pairs_shortest_paths Yes, I know it's not exactly what you're looking for. But it's likely to give you the answer, anyway.

Comment: Thanks @rici it seems to be ok.

Comment: I edited the question @D.W.

Comment: [A multiple pairs shortest path algorithm](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25769268).

Comment: Thanks @YuvalFilmus

Comment: Please don't use "EDIT".  Instead, revise the question so it reads well for someone who encounters the question for the first time.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755